# ClasscastException handling issues

Tags: java, exception

I went through one of the code where code is written as below ,

```
try{ 
    ((classA) object).setCustomContext(currentObjectContext.getContext()) 
}catch(ClassCastException e){
    // In that case convert it into classB as not classA
    // and conversion code is written below 
}
```

Issues/Concern/Queries :

1. `instanceOf()` is not used which is good point but still runtimeException we need to catch for such type of condition irritates.
2. For above scenario rather than catching exception and processing to classB before exception caught we need identify the type of object and need to convert into respective class ?
3. As I know each time solving runtime exception by handling it in such way is not correct/good java practice  when there is huge traffic over this piece of chunk of code.
4. Anybody has better solution for such type of handling

(Please note classA and classB are from different third party libraries)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the actual question here is, because you pretty much answered it yourself: Before casting an object to a specific type, use instanceof, .isInstance() or .isAssignableFrom() in an if/else statement to make sure the cast won't fail (it also gives you better error handling if a cast is not possible). Ie. something like:

```
if (object instanceof classA) {
  ((classA) object).setCustomContext(currentObjectContext.getContext())
} else if (object instanceof classB) {
  ((classB) object).setCustomContext(currentObjectContext.getContext())
} else {
  throw new IllegalStateException("Object is of unsupported type: "+object.getClass());
}
```

If that is not what you're after, please clarify your question.

Comment: Not looking for instance of... Looking for better approach to solve this issue

Comment: Then more context is required for the question. Why is instanceof not the solution you are looking for? Your question is very narrow as it stands now.